# How do I do data manipulation on the client side in React Query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am working on an vocabulary app that displays words that users have added in a card format. I am using react query's `useQuery` hook to fetch the data from my backend and displaying them on the frontend. Now I am trying to implement a search functionality; basically I want to filter the cards based on the user's search query.

I have tried implementing it in a the custom hook that I am using the fetch the words from my backend; using the `select` option in `useQuery` I am filtering out the words and returning the one that matches the user's query. However, my issue is that I cannot get the UI to update as the user is searching for a word. Here is my custom hook that is in charge of fetching and manipulating the data:

```
function useGetWords() {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');

  const handleSearchQuery = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSearchQuery(e.target.value);
  };

  const filteredWords = useCallback(
    (words: VocabModel[]) => {
      if (!searchQuery) return words;

      return words.filter((word: VocabModel) =>
        word.word.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase()),
      );
    },
    [searchQuery],
  );
  const {
    isLoading,
    data: words = [],
    error,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['words', searchQuery],
    queryFn: fetchWords,
    select: filteredWords,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    retry: 2,
  });

  return { isLoading, words, error, searchQuery, handleSearchQuery };
}

export default useGetWords;
```

And here is the sidebar where I am hooking up the `searchQuery` and `handleSearchQuery`:

```
function Sidebar({ onDismiss, children }: SidebarProps) {
  const { searchQuery, handleSearchQuery } = useGetWords();
  console.log(searchQuery);

  return (
    <>
      <aside className="px-2 py-4 sm:w-[250px] sm:border-r">
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-3 mx-3">
          <Button
            onPress={onDismiss}
            className="w-full hover:bg-primary/60 text-stone-100"
            color="primary"
            startContent={<PlusCircleIcon className="w-5 h-5" />}
          >
            <span className="font-semibold capitalize">Add word</span>
          </Button>
          <Input
            placeholder="Search..."
            type="text"
            radius="md"
            startContent={<MagnifyingGlassIcon className="w-5 h-5" />}
            onChange={handleSearchQuery}
          />
        </div>
        <p>{searchQuery}</p>
      </aside>

      {children}
    </>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

The hook up works because I am displaying what the user types, but the UI does not update. I have looked all over the Tanstack/react-query docs and online and the solution is to do data manipulation in the select option (also to wrap the function in a useCallback). I have also experimented with passing the searchQuery to the queryKey and that does not work. I think there is something I am missing. I am still learning react query and if someone can help, that would be great. Thanks

Comment: I would probably choose `useEffect()` here for this and pass in the parameters.  It works in the way you are describing, but it acts as a listener and updates (re renders) when it detects changes to said states/hooks.  I am assuming you'll get an answer from someone that will be using [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) -- Also read [You Might Not Need an Effect](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect) to prevent overuse and bloating your App

Comment: Are you saying to choose `useEffect()` over `useCallback()`? I thought react query is supposed to cause a rerender once the `searchQuery` changes since it's passed into the `queryKey`. I have also considered doing the data manipulation outside of react query and just manually updating the UI using vanilla react but that would defeat the purpose of using react query imo

Comment: select shouldn't be necessary when searchQuery is already included in the queryKey. With that implementation, the searching should happen server-side, but since you mention select, I'm unsure if your filtering happens on the backend or in the browser?